# Filter effect not coming while converting canvas image to toDataURL()

Tags: javascript, image, svg, canvas, filter

I want the filter effect of an image while converting to base64 image .

```
$scope.maskCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('viewport');          
$scope.maskctx = $scope.maskCanvas.getContext("2d");  
$scope.maskctx.filter = 'contrast(200%)';  
console.log($scope.maskCanvas.toDataURL);
```

Above code reflecting on canvas but not reflecting on base64 image.

Comment: can you add a [mcve] to the question please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By hit and trial accidentally got the answer .
Instead of using

```
$scope.maskCanvas.toDataURL();
```

we should use

```
$scope.maskctx.canvas.toDataURL();
```